# Can I use my iPhone 4 sim in another iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, sim

I was just wondering if I am able to use my current iPhone 4 sim in another iPhone 4 because my current phone is breaking. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
But beware of locked iPhones. Some iPhones might be locked to other wireless carriers.